# Issue compiling thrift 0.9.0 c++ client

Tags: c++, ubuntu, thrift

I have tried compiling a cpp application with thrift 0.9.0 on ubuntu precise32:

```
g++ hello_client.cpp gen-cpp/HelloSvc.cpp -lthrift
```

However, this results in:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TSocket.h:25:0,
                 from hello_client.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TTransport.h:34:1: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
/usr/local/include/thrift/transport/TTransport.h:107:3: error: 'uint32_t' does not name a type
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to fix 0.9.0 by:

1) Install python-dev (I noticed an error: missing python.h when building thrift)

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

2) Building thrift with:

```
./configure CPPFLAGS="-DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H"
```

Still the same errors, so I decided to checkout, build and install the latest thrift (HEAD version 6f2a5037105ccad05eb84ec0a60da3389c85eb3f in git).

With the latest thrift, there were no errors building the cpp client.  However, running `a.out` returned an error:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so: cannot open 
         shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the newly built thrift library fixed this:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$THRIFT_SRC/lib/cpp/.libs/`