# Error while running cpp thrift generated code

Tags: c++, thrift

I created a simple apache thrift file, and generated cpp code. When I ran the compiled and ran the cpp code,
it gives the following error.

./test: error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I had compiled thrift from source, and had not seen any issues while compiling thrift.

Can someone please elaborate is the issue here and how exactly do I get around it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551531/issue-compiling-thrift-0-9-0-c-client - I'd really love when people would start to use a search engine before asking already answered questions. It took me 20 seconds to find that.

Comment: Setup evn_var as per instruction given here, [Set path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43470846/2050511)

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so /usr/lib/libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so /usr/lib64/libthrift-1.0.0-dev.so
```

Or

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

Answer (score 0):

Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the newly built thrift library should fix it. (taken from [Issue compiling thrift 0.9.0 c++ client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551531/issue-compiling-thrift-0-9-0-c-client))