# libthrift-0.9.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, thrift

I have installed `thrift 0.9.1` using the git repository.
After building thrift I started the precompiled cpp Server and and the php client. This precompiled examples worked fine.

Now I am trying to compile my own cpp Server by following this tutorial (http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/ThriftUsageC++). 
I used:

`g++ -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H -DHAVE_NETINET_IN_H -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift *.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lthrift -o something`

to compile the server which worked without errors.

When I execute the server by typing `./something` I get `error while loading shared libraries: libthrift-0.9.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

In the lib directory are the following files:

- libthrift.a
- libtrift.la
- libthrift.so
- libtthrift-0.9.0.so
- libtthrift-0.9.1.so

There are also `libthrift_c.glib.a`, `libthriftnb.a` and `libthriftz.a` and the files which belong to them, but I think they are not important for this error.

Somebody knows what's the fault?

Thx for any help

Comment: need to properly set up your LD_LIBRARY_PATH (unix) so that the dynamic libraries are found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a dynamic library is used (`-lthrift`), Linux searches for the directory containing `libthrift.so` in the directories within the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, you must make sure that the directory containing `libthrift.so` is setup correctly in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks, I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH by following this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux"

Answer (score 3):

```
Set env_var as follows,
$vim ~/.bashrc
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
$source ~/.bashrc
$echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$thrift -version
```

Comment: ```export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/```
also works.